# Should I prefer composition or inheritance in this scenario?

Tags: object-oriented, object-oriented-design, inheritance, composition

Consider an interface:

```
interface IWaveGenerator
{
    SoundWave GenerateWave(double frequency, double lengthInSeconds);
}
```

This interface is implemented by a number of classes which generate waves of different shapes (for example, `SineWaveGenerator` and `SquareWaveGenerator`).

I want to implement a class that generates a `SoundWave` based on musical data, not raw sound data. It would receive the name of a note and a length in terms of beats (not seconds), and internally use the `IWaveGenerator` functionality to create a `SoundWave` accordingly.

Question is, should the `NoteGenerator` contain an `IWaveGenerator` or should it inherit from an `IWaveGenerator` implementation?

I'm leaning towards composition because of two reasons:

1- It allows me to inject any `IWaveGenerator` to the `NoteGenerator` dynamically. Also, I only need one `NoteGenerator` class, instead of `SineNoteGenerator`, `SquareNoteGenerator`, etc.

2- There's no need for `NoteGenerator` to expose the lower-level interface defined by `IWaveGenerator`.

However I'm posting this question to hear other opinions regarding this, maybe points I haven't thought of.

BTW: I would say `NoteGenerator` *is* conceptually an `IWaveGenerator` because it generates `SoundWave`s.

Answer (score 14):

> It allows me to inject any IWaveGenerator to the NoteGenerator dynamically. Also, I only need one NoteGenerator class, instead of **SineNoteGenerator**, **SquareNoteGenerator**, etc.

That is a clear sign it would be better to use composition here, and not inherit from `SineGenerator` or `SquareGenerator` or (worse) both. Nethertheless, it will make sense to inherit a NoteGenerator directly from an `IWaveGenerator` if you change the latter a little bit.

The **real problem** here is, it is probably meaningful to have `NoteGenerator` with a method like

```
SoundWave GenerateWave(string noteName, double noOfBeats, IWaveGenerator waveGenerator);
```

but not with a method

```
SoundWave GenerateWave(double frequency, double lengthInSeconds);
```

because this interface is too specific. You want `IWaveGenerator`s to be objects which generate `SoundWave`s, but currently your interface expresses *`IWaveGenerator`s are objects which generate `SoundWave`s **from frequency and length exclusively*** . So better design such an interface this way

```
interface IWaveGenerator
{
    SoundWave GenerateWave();
}
```

and pass parameters like `frequency` or `lengthInSeconds`, or a completely different set of parameters through the constructors of a `SineWaveGenerator`, a `SquareGenerator`, or whatever other generator you have in mind. This will allow you to create other kind of `IWaveGenerator`s with completely different construction parameters. Maybe you want to add a rectangle wave generator which needs a frequency and two length parameters, or something like that, maybe you want to add a triangle wave generator next, also with at least three parameters. Or, a `NoteGenerator`, with constructor parameters `noteName`, `noOfBeats`, and `waveGenerator`.

So the general solution here is to decouple the input parameters from the output function, and make only the output function part of the interface.

Comment: Interesting, haven't thought of this. But I wonder: does this (setting the 'parameters to a polymorphic function' in the constructor) often work in reality? Because then the code would indeed have to know what type it's dealing with, thus ruining Polymorphism. Can you give an example where this would work?

Comment: @AvivCohn: "the code would indeed have to know what type it's dealing with" - no, that is a misconception. Only the part of the code which constructs the specific type of generator (mybe a factory), and that has to know *always* which type it's dealing with.

Comment: ... and if you need to make the construction process of your objects polymorphic, you can use the "abstract factory" pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

Comment: This is the solution I would pick.  Small, immutable classes is the right way to go here.

Answer (score 9):

Whether or not NoteGenerator is "conceptually" an IWaveGenerator does not matter.

You should only inherit from an interface if you plan on implementing that exact interface according to the Liskov Substitution Principle, i.e. with the correct semantics as well as the correct syntax.

It sounds like your NoteGenerator might have syntactically the same interface, but its semantics (in this case, the meanings of the parameters it takes) will be very different, so using inheritance in this case would be highly misleading and potentially error-prone. You're right to prefer composition here.

Comment: Actually I didn't mean `NoteGenerator` would implement `GenerateWave` but interpret the parameters differently, yes I agree that would be a terrible idea. I meant NoteGenerator is kind of a specialization of a wave generator: it's able to take in 'higher level' input data instead of just raw sound data (e.g. a note name instead of a frequency). I.e. `sineWaveGenerator.generate(440) == noteGenerator.generate("a4")`. So there comes the question, composition or inheritance.

Comment: If you can come up with a single interface that fits both the high and low level wave generation classes, then inheritance can be acceptable. But that seems very difficult, and unlikely to have any real benefits. Composition definitely seems like the more natural choice.

Comment: @Ixrec: actually, it is not very difficult to have a single interface for all types of generators, the OP should probably do both, use composition to inject a low level generator **and** inherit from a simplified interface (but not inherit the NoteGenerator from a low level generator implementation) See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

> 2- There's no need for NoteGenerator to expose the lower-level
>   interface defined by IWaveGenerator.

Sounds like `NoteGenerator` is not a `WaveGenerator`, so therefore should not implement the interface.

Composition is the correct choice.

Comment: I would say `NoteGenerator` *is* conceptually an `IWaveGenerator` because it generates `SoundWave`s.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't need to expose `GenerateWave`, then it's not an `IWaveGenerator`. But it sounds like it _uses_ a IWaveGenerator (maybe more?), hence composition.

Comment: @EricKing: this is a correct answer as long as one has to stick to the `GenerateWave` function as it is written in the question. But from the comment above I guess that is not what the OP really had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You have a solid case for composition.  You may have a case to *also* add inheritance.  The way to tell is by looking at the calling code.  If you want to be able to use a `NoteGenerator` in existing calling code that expects an `IWaveGenerator`, then you need to implement the interface.  You're looking for a need for substitutability.   Whether it conceptually "is-a" wave generator is beside the point.

Comment: In that case, i.e. choosing composition, but still needing that inheritance in order to make substitutability happen, the "inheritance" would be named e.g. `IHasWaveGenerator`, and the relevant method on that interface would be `GetWaveGenerator` which returns an instance of `IWaveGenerator`. Of course naming can be changed. (I'm just trying to flesh out more details - let me know if my details are wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

It is fine for `NoteGenerator` to implement the interface, and also, for `NoteGenerator` to have an internal implementation that references (by composition) another `IWaveGenerator`.

Generally, composition results in more maintainable (i.e. readable) code, because you don't have complexities of overrides to reason over.  Your observation about the matrix of classes you'd have when using inheritance is also on point, and can probably be thought of as a code smell pointing toward composition.

Inheritance is better used when you have an implementation that you want to specialize or customize, which doesn't seem to be the case here: you just need to use the interface.

Comment: It is not OK for `NoteGenerator` to implement `IWaveGenerator` because because notes require beats. not seconds-.

Comment: Yes, certainly if there is no sensible implementation of the interface, then the class should not implement it.  However, the OP did state that "I would say `NoteGenerator` is conceptually an `IWaveGenerator` because it generates `SoundWave`s", and, he was considering inheritance, so I took mental latitude for the possibility that there might be some implementation of the interface, even though there is another better interface or signature for the class.